# Searching Model with Many to Many Polymorphic Relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationships

Following the [tags example in the Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations), I've successfully implemented image tagging, and now I'm trying to search by said tags.

Pulling an image from a single tag works well, but I'm hitting a roadblock when trying to search for images containing multiple tags.

This is the closest I've gotten, and it works as expected but it is not what I desire.

```
/**
* $tag string, example: 'baseball'
* $tags array, example: ['baseball','stadium','new.york.yankees']
*/
Image::whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tag,$tags) {
    if (count($tags)) {
        // Retrieves images tagged as 'baseball' OR 'stadium' OR 'new.york.yankees'
        // Instead, I want it to retrieve images that have all three tags
        $query->whereIn('tag', $tags);

        // The following returns no results, though there are images tagged correctly.
        // I presume this is an incorrect approach.
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $query->where('tag', '=', $tag);
        }
    } else {
        // Retrieves images tagged as 'baseball'
        $query->where('tag', '=', $tag);
    }
})->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->paginate(config('app.images_per_page'))
```

I'm stumped, overtired, and getting nowhere while searching for similar examples. What am I missing? What is the correct terminology for what I am trying to achieve, so I can add it to my vocabulary for future endeavors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this just needs to be a whereHas statement for each of the tags you are trying to filter by.  This would create an AND statement within the query.

```
if(!$count($tags)) $tags = [$tag]; //for simplicity lets always have an array

$imageQuery = Image::query();
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $imageQuery = $imageQuery->whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tag) {
        $query->where('tag', '=', $tag);
    });
}
$results = $imageQuery->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(config('app.images_per_page'))->get();
```

Code is not tested but logically I think you need a where clause for each tag

Comment: I see, so rather than processing my loop inside my `whereHas`, I need to loop to have multiple `whereHas` calls. This works beautifully. Thanks for the help!